# Contain a number just once in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, int

How do I make an array contain a number just once?From any random numbers added to a textbox i need to first convert them to ints then with the separator i make the program understand the separate ints but how do I an int to be counted in the result list of ints just once?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could start with using a HashSet as the collection type (.Net 3.5 and higher).  This will disallow duplicate values.  Then, if you can't use the HashSet as is, you can call .ToArray on it.

That is:

```
 HashSet<int>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Distinct method

```
input.Split(new char[]{separator},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
     .Select(x=>int.Parse(x))
     .Distinct();
```

---

If you want to avoid LINQ

```
var array=input.Split(new char[]{separator},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var set=new HashSet<int>();
foreach(var x in array)set.Add(int.Parse(x));
var unique=set.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts but I'am a sort of newbie and I'm still trying to avoid LINQ,scares me for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ's [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) method to remove the duplicates:

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 2, 3 };
numbers = numbers.Distinct().ToArray(); // 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384015%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) to check if an item already exists in an array. I'd suggest using a generic collection such as a List or Dictionary instead, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check LINQ method [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx)

Example use:

```
  List<int> ages = new List<int> { 21, 46, 46, 55, 17, 21, 55, 55 };

            IEnumerable<int> distinctAges = ages.Distinct();

            Console.WriteLine("Distinct ages:");

            foreach (int age in distinctAges)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(age);
            }

            /*
             This code produces the following output:

             Distinct ages:
             21
             46
             55
             17
            */
```